# how make invisible the password with Mailkit in Authenticate if the SMTP server requires authentication?

Tags: c#, smtpclient, mailkit

I understand that SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols so the recommendation is use MailKit, but with SmtpClient using System.Net.Mail the password was not required. With Mailkit I must Authanticate with password in my code.

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
                client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

                client.Send (message);
                client.Disconnect (true);
            }
```

Could I don't use the password visible in my code, please ? How ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could load the password from an XML (or JSON or any other format) config file.

It's also possible that your SMTP server doesn't require authentication, so you should at least check that.

Comment: This can be downloaded from server too :) This is not security releated way!

Comment: Hi, yes, but if somebody has an acces to the server he can lock the password. we can crypt this in the web.config like tge connection string for the dat base ? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

this is my way of doing this:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Password")
```

You need to go to Environment variables in Windows settings:

[image]

Now:

[image]

Nazwa zmiennej = Environment variable (Password)
Wartość zmiennej = value (your password)

Remember to reload Visual Studio after adding Environment variable because VS load it at the start.

Your code with my method will look like this:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
                client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate ("joey", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Password"));

                client.Send (message);
                client.Disconnect (true);
            }
```

Comment: please dont vote - before checking! this is right answer!

Comment: Hi, I didn't know this, but my project it's a web site.

Comment: doesnt matter, try it.

Comment: I can not. It's not my server. it's a site web hosted.